# MySQL - Select Concat an entire row

Tags: sql, mysql, group-concat, concatenation

How can I select and concat every field in a row?

I want to do something similar to this:

```
SELECT concat(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name')
as single FROM tbl_name
```

..but obviously the above doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that you will need to select `where table_name = 'tbl_name' and table_schema = 'schema_name'`.  There may be multiple tables with the same name but in different schemata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have the build the query dynamically, i.e. list all columns in `concat(...)` explicitly. You can do that on the client side by running two queries or in a stored procedure using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 steps:

1- Build field list

```
SELECT group_concat( column_name ) as field_list
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
GROUP BY table_name
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

2- Copy the value of field_list field

3- Extract data:

```
SELECT CONCAT( "Paste value copied at previous step" )
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

If you create a stored procedure, than you can combine the above steps